# How to prove these two Graphs not isomorphic? [From Discrete Mathematics with Applications 7th Edition by Susanna Epp Chapter 10.4 Exercise 13]

Tags: graph-isomorphism

Here are the graphs.

[image]

The problem comes from exercise 13 of chapter 10.4 (Discrete Mathematics 7th Edition by Susanna Epp).

Could someone show me whether or not these two graphs are isomorphic? Why?

Both number of vertices in $G$ and $G^\prime$ are $8$. Both number of edges in $G$ and $G^\prime$ are $12$. Every vertex has degree $3$.

My guess is that they are not isomorphic.

Thank You.

Comment: To see what’s going on, it may be helpful to realize that $G'$ is isomorphic to the [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) $Q_3$, the graph whose vertices are the vertices of an ordinary cube, and whose edges are the edges of that cube.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like every vertex in $G$ is on a cycle of length $5,$ but $G'$ has no cycles of length 5.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove it is to show that the vertices of $G'$ can be colored with $2$ colors in such a way that adjacent vertices never get the same color, but $G$ cannot. In technical terms, the [*chromatic number*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984132/if-n-choose-1-0-mod-2-n-choose-2-0-mod-2-n-choose-n-1-0-mod-2-then/1984203#1984203) of $G'$ is $2$, while that of $G$ is greater than $2$.